# PHP Datetime with TBD time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

this question has proven hard to search for, so i'm hoping I can get an answer here.

on my site I allow users to enter a date and a time for an event. they can also select that the date and/or time is TBD (i.e. they will enter it later when they know it). with a TBD date it's easy enough, just store it as NULL in MySQL. the problem arises when they know the date but not the time. in the past I have simply stored the time as 00:00:00 (midnight). it works, and I highly doubt anyone would create an event at midnight, but has anyone had any luck with another solution?

thanks.

Comment: Store Date and Time separately in `DATE` and `TIME` fields. Then you have the option of storing `NULL` in either or both of them.

Comment: good thought, i was hoping that wasn't the only option.

Comment: @MikeW My apologies, I must have been thinking of something else

Comment: I use an odd seconds time - `00:00:59` | `00:00:01` | `00:00:41` - since events are usually set by minutes, not seconds. So if the event has the default seconds time, I set it as null in my select query or pup code.

Comment: not a bad thought. i actually like that, because i don't even give my users the option to edit the seconds. thanks!